# get selected content of webview in windows8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, webview

In WebView control, we can select content, is it possible to get the selected content of the WebView? I don't find event such as "SelectedText" in this TextBox, anyone can help?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want the user to copy text and retrieve that text you can simply let them highlight the text, use the copy command, and retrieve the content in code like so:             var text = await Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.GetContent().GetTextAsync()

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to copy the text, only want to get the selected text by user, like SelectedText property of TextBlock.

Answer (score 0):

[WebView.ScriptNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227713) can help you